# QCombobox overlaps other widgets when added a new item

Tags: qt, layout, qcombobox

I see this wierd behavoir happening with QComboBox, it doesn't update as soon as its contents change. To demonstrate the issue here is a sample code and some screen shots.

Initial widget
[image]

Add Item to combobox [image] (See how the checkbox is overlapped)

Manually resized updates and adjusts the layout & combobox[image]

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtGui>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QWidget parentWidget;
    QCheckBox checker;
    QComboBox comber;
    QHBoxLayout layoot;

    comber.setEditable (true);
    comber.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QComboBox::AdjustToContents);

    layoot.addWidget (&comber);
    layoot.addWidget (&checker);
    parentWidget.setLayout(&layoot);

    parentWidget.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

I tried update() and repaint() on the combobox and also the layout after the item is edited but doesn't have any effect.
Do I really have to manually resize the widget for the combobox to readjust?? Is anyone aware of a fix for this problem??

Thank you.

CV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a bug to me, especially if manually calling `update` on the layout is having no effect. Perhaps what you are seeing is [this bug](https://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTBUG-2559). Apparently that one is fixed in 4.8.0.

Comment: Yep, I just tested it with Qt 4.8 and it works fine. but not in Qt 4.7.4. Thanks Troubadour

Answer (score 0):

I agree it's kinda weird behaviour...
adding `parentWidget.resize(parentWidget.sizeHint()) ;` after adding text solved the problem, but it's more a hack than an answer.

edit :
ok, did you try the `QComboBox::AdjustToContentsOnFirstShow` sizeAdjustPolicy instead ? Does it fit your needs ? At least it solves the problem even for an embedded widget as well

Comment: This probably only works if the parentWidget contains the combobox,  if the combobox is in a floating QWidget which is a child of a QMainWindow then there's no way other than manually resizing the floating QWidget